# How do you navigate to another component that does not receive the props of react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm working with React Native and React Navigation.

I have a component called App.js in which I declare the Drawer Navigation of React-Navigation.

In this I have an option to log out but I can not navigate to another component after removing the AsyncStorage

Does anyone know how to achieve it?

Thank you.

This is my code:

**App.js**

```
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const customDrawerComponent = (props) => (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView>
                <DrawerItems
                    {...props}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.button} onPress={this.logOut} >
                    <Text> Logout </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
);

logOut = () => {
        // NOT WORKS
        // this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')

        //NOT WORKS:
    this.myAction();
}

myAction = () => {
    const nav = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'App',
    });
    return nav;
  };

const AppDrawNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    MainComponent: { screen: MainComponent,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
          }) },
    Login: { screen: LoginComponent,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
          }) },
    User: { screen: UsersComponent }
    },
    {
        contentComponent: customDrawerComponent,
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

make this as a class like

export default class App extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not works: **"Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined"** :(

Answer (score 0):

Your logout function is declared outside of the Navigator. This means you don't have access to the navigation prop there. However, your customDrawerComponent is a screen of your Navigator and it should have access to it.

So you can  try something like this (props here are the props passed to the customDrawerComponent):

```
onPress={()=> {props.navigation.navigate("Login")}}
```

Plus your App.js seems kind of strange since you're not exporting any component. Have you pasted the whole code of App.js or just parts of it?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that either you want to :-

1. navigate from outside the components
2. navigate from components which do not have navigation prop.

For this I have tried 2 solutions and both work extremely fine though I based towards the second one.

**First Solution**

Use **withNavigation** from `react-navigation` package. If your components are deeply nested they wont have navigation prop unless u specify them manually or put them in context ;passing navigation prop becomes a real pain. So instead use **withNavigation** and your component would have navigation prop.

```
import {withNavigation} from "react-navigation";

const Component = ({navigation}) => {
  const onPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate(//ROUTE_NAME//)
  }
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <Text>Navigate</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default withNavigation(Component);
```

**Second Solution**

Create a helper script and use that.

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import {NavigationActions} from "react-navigation";

let _container; // eslint-disable-line


export const navigation = {
  mapProps: (SomeComponent) => {
    return class extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = SomeComponent.navigationOptions; // better use hoist-non-react-statics
      render () {
        const {navigation: {state: {params}}} = this.props;
        return <SomeComponent {...params} {...this.props} />;
      }
    }
  },
  setContainer: (container) => {
    _container = container;
  },
  reset: (routeName, params) => {
    _container.dispatch(
      NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({
            type: "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
            routeName,
            params
          })
        ]
      })
    );
  },
  goBack: () => {
    _container.dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
  },
  navigate: (routeName, params) => {
    _container.dispatch(
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        type: "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
        routeName,
        params
      })
    );
  },
  navigateDeep: (actions) => {
    _container.dispatch(
      actions.reduceRight(
        (prevAction, action) =>
          NavigationActions.navigate({
            type: "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
            routeName: action.routeName,
            params: action.params,
            action: prevAction
          }),
        undefined
      )
    );
  },
  getCurrentRoute: () => {
    if (!_container || !_container.state.nav) {
      return null;
    }

    return _container.state.nav.routes[_container.state.nav.index] || null;
  }
};
```

In your parent component when you mount the navigation call following:-

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import App from "./routes";
import {navigation} from "utils";

class Setup extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <App
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          navigation.setContainer(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now, in your components you can directly use helpers from this script itself and navigation would be accessibly globally now.

```
import {navigate} from "utils/navigation";
```

For more details you can [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1439#issuecomment-303661539) thread